# XCode run layout mode

Tags: ios, xcode

Before I ran the app and it was in portrait mode. To change in landscape mode from the iOS Simulator I used Hardware->Rotate

Now, I don't know what I have accidentally changed, whenever I run the app the layout "automatically rotates" to landscape mode... 
If I choose Hardware->Rotate it doesn't go to portrait mode but ehm... "really"... rotates it by 90°!!?

What have I messed up? How can I reset the Run to start in portrait mode?

Comment: Run the app and let it change to landscape. Rotate it back to portrait then stop the app. Also worth quitting the simulator at this point. Next time you run it should start in Portrait. I have had that happen a few times and that usually fixes it.

Comment: Are you rotating to portrait upside down which you've not set as a supported orientation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it!
Just use Rotate left multiple times!

It cycles through:
 portrait -> landscape -> landscape vertical -> landscape -> portrait...